# Get times in service that run in a repeat AlarmManage

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I start a repeat task in AlarmManager,but how can i get the repeat counts in service.
here is code
MyActivity

`mAlarmSender = PendingIntent.getService(MyActivity.this,0, new     Intent(MyActivity2.this, AutoBuild.class), 0);`

```
    long firstTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
            firstTime, 1000 * 5, mAlarmSender);
```

AutoBuild

`public class AutoBuild extends Service {`

```
private String[] infos;

private Intent mIntent;

private String pathStr;

static final String TAG = "AutoBuild";

private int i=0;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    this.mIntent = intent;

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    mNM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    printData(i);/**print result*/

    i++;/*count ++*/

    AutoBuild.this.stopSelf();/*stop service */

}

private void printData(int i) {     

   Log.i(TAG, i + "");    
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return mBinder;
}

private final IBinder mBinder = new Binder() {

    @Override
    protected boolean onTransact(int code, Parcel data, Parcel reply,
                                 int flags) throws RemoteException {
        return super.onTransact(code, data, reply, flags);
    }
};
```

}

the value of i always 0:Is there anyway can change this value when Alarmanage repeat

Answer (score 0):

The thing with `Service` is that it runs as a single instance. Everytime you start the same service, only the `onStartCommand()` method is called. Hence if you are using an `alarmManager` and wants to change a variable in `Service` you may do it in the `onStartCommand()`. The `onCreate()` is called only once when the `Service` starts for the first time and hence in your case the variable `i` doesn't change after successive calls to `Service`.

Check the following for more details:
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService

Comment: NO,Indeed,in these condition onStartCommand ,onCreate() always called when alarm repeat.no matter the variable where you changed it still the same